# Doctrine ODM: get array of specific fields

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

So, the problem is to get ids (or any another fields) in one array, like:

```
[
    "someId1",
    "someId2",
    "someId3",
]
```

I tried to take it by next query:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('_id')
        ->hydrate(false)
        ->getQuery()
        ->toArray()
```

but I took not what I want, but near this:

```
112 => array:1 [
  "_id" => 112
]
113 => array:1 [
  "_id" => 113
]
114 => array:1 [
  "_id" => 114
]
```

(I use strategy INCREMENT). I tried do this by map, reduce, but I understood that I know nothing in these functions :). So can somebody help me?

P.S: I know how to realise this with php functions, like `array_keys | array_values`. But I really want to know how to do it by mongoDB, and particularly, in ODM with createQueryBuilder

Comment: This is ORM so try to adapt this to your ODM: In repo `public function findIds()
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->select('partial c.{id}')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
    }` then `$ids = $this->yourRepository->findIds(); $result  = array_column($ids, 'id');` in your service.

Comment: ORM and ODM **NOT** is the same. Just read the documentation the core of this projects

Answer (score 0):

This usually can be done by creating a custom hydrator. You could take a look at this example and try to adapt it to ODM https://gist.github.com/Tom32i/7984541

Comment: The hydration in ODM has only 2 params: **true, false**, that means result in object view or in array view - that's it. So I think its not useful advice.

Comment: @Nikita_kharkov_ua Are you sure? So why there's a hydrator interface http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/mongodb_odm/1.0/class-Doctrine.ODM.MongoDB.Hydrator.HydratorInterface.html and an option to set Hydrators namespace http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/introduction.html#setup ?

Comment: You open my eyes! But! No one usage example for this - this is the **first** important thing. **Second** - no such method like in ORM setHydrator. Only **hydrate(true | false)**.
Now I have similar task with hydration: get object with reference, and in array of references must be only ids, not full object. Sure, I can get object and map it to take needle values. But I fully sure that mongoDB support fetching results in custom represent.

Comment: https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/issues/1617#issuecomment-315141027 - discussing about this problem